# Code Snippets and touch devices - how?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I always use a touch device with a large screen. I added a code snippet this week for the first time without problems.

Today I get the *Code snippets not available on touch devices* message, so I tried setting the browser to desktop, still didn't work. Just tried it again now, in the same browser, and it works?

So -  should it work or not, and if it does, could a browser restart have sorted this?  Is this a bug or just odd browser behavior?